# How do I implement adding and removing elements of an array?

Tags: c++

How to implement output of all elements of an array?
A task:
N guys are arranged in a circle. Starting the countdown from the 1st, each k is removed, closing the circle after each removal. Who is left? Display the order of removal from the circle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int counter(int n, int k) {
    int function = n >= 1 ? (counter (n - 1, k) + k - 1) % n + 1: 1;
    return function;
};

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
      
    int peoples;
    int quantity;

    std::cin >> peoples;
    std::cin >> quantity;
      
    std::cout << "Remaining : " << counter(peoples, quantity);
    return 0;
}
```

My code outputs the remaining one item.
How to implement replenishment of an array with elements.

```
for (i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
    cout << ?;
}
```

output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
something like this)

and how can you implement the removal of array elements
for example deleting every third array element in a circle
Output:

`1 2 3 4 5`

`1 2 4 5`

`2 4 5`

`2 4`

`4`

Comment: You cannot add or remove elements from an array. Arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: but just search about `vector`, then you can.

Comment: can be more? did not quite understand you

Comment: Let me be more direct: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a container that allows you to easily manage a dynamic random access sequence, which you apparently want.

Comment: This is one heck of an ambiguous question bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I implement adding and removing elements of an array?

There is no way to add or remove elements from an array. An array has a constant number of elements that doesn't change through the life of the array.

If you need to represent a dynamic sequence of objects that can grow or shrink, you need a more complex data structure. `std::vector` is an implementation of such data structure. You can add using `std::vector::push_back` and remove using `std::vector::erase`.